# Regex to match text inside a double tag in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need help getting the tagged values from a file.

Inside the file I have the below tags:

```
<<Name>>
<Male>>
<<female>
School>>
<<DVD
<Name>
Name>
<ball>
<$Date$>
<#Emp NO#>
```

I need a result collection as shown below:

```
<<Name>>
<Male>>
<<female>
School>>
<<DVD
<Name>
Name>
<ball>
```

I am using below code:

```
public const string REGEX = @"\<<*[A-Za-z0-9_!@#\$%\s\-]*\>>"

MatchCollection matchColl = Regex.Matches(s, Constants.REGEX, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I need lines without # symbol and $ symbol.

Comment: This `Name>` does not look like a tag.

Comment: i need to catch all the enclosed tag values.

Comment: Like `School>>`? It does not look enclosed. BTW, try `<?<?[A-Za-z0-9_!@#$%\s-]*>?>|<?<[A-Za-z0-9_!@#$%\s-]*>?>?`. Or even `<?<?[\w!@#$%\s-]*>?>|<?<[\w!@#$%\s-]*>?>?` with ECMAScript flag.

Comment: your input is hardly understandable

Comment: You want to have lines witout # symobl and $ symbol, yes?

Comment: yes you are correct.

Comment: Above given code piece is not working. its eliminated School>>
Name> and also included <$Date$>
<#Emp NO#>

Comment: Can any one answers this question.

Comment: No need posting duplicates, that will not help you get an answer quicker. You should think about improving the current question (provide more context, explain the rules for matching the patterns), then help will arrive sooner than later. BTW, I posted a possible regex (even 2) in the comment above, and received no feedback. There is an answer - you left no feedback. How do you want to get an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try like this - but I don't know if I answer to Your question

```
  var input = new List<string> { "<$Date$>", "<#Emp NO#>","< ball >","Name>" };

  var result = input.Where(l => !Regex.IsMatch(l, ".*[$|#].*"));
```

It is working. Pattern is NOT [somethig zero or more][ $ or # ][somethig zero or more]

```
Result is {"< ball >","Name>" }
```

You can change the code to adopt to Your solution

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove lines with $ & # symbol use !Regex.IsMatch(InputString, @"[$#]")